# Draw a Circle in 3D space facing towards Direction Vector

Tags: python, math, vector, graphics, geometry

I will try to explain as clearly as possible.

**Goal**: Draw a Set of circular point around a center point in 3D space facing towards the direction vector. Trying to model a Cylinder and bend model using VTK python, for that generating points in 3D space and later on join them to put a Surface on it.

**Approach:** Let's say I have a Center Point **center**(x,y,z) and direction vector **direction_vector**. I will compute Orthogonal Basis on point **center** define a plane and generate points on the plane pointing towards the direction vector.

```
def generate_circular_points_v2(center, radius, direction_vector, num_points=12):
circular_points = []
v1 = np.cross(direction_vector, [1.0, 0.0, 0.0])
if np.all(v1 == 0):
    v1 = np.cross(direction_vector, [0.0, 1.0, 0.0])   
v2 = np.cross(direction_vector, v1)

v1 /= np.linalg.norm(v1)
v2 /= np.linalg.norm(v2)
angles = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, num=num_points, endpoint=False)
for angle in angles:
    v1_Out = np.cos(angle) * v1 
    v2_Out = np.sin(angle) * v2
    point = center + (radius * (v1_Out + v2_Out ))
    circular_points.append(point)

return circular_points
```

The code below draws a bezier curve and then add circular rings on each point of the curve.

```
        # generating points for Bezier Curve
        # it takes 3 Control points, 1st one is starting point, 2nd on is Tangent Intersection Point
        # and 3rd one is the ending point, it makes a 90 degrees angle bend
        pointListBEND = []
        for i in range(0 , 10):
            i=i/10
            pts = quadratic_bezier(ptsA ,cornerPointBend , ptsB , t = i)
            pointListBEND.append(pts)
        # GENERATING Circular Rings on each Point of Bezier Curze
        for itr in range(0,len(pointListBEND)):

            if itr + 1 < len(pointListBEND):
                dirVec = getNormalizedDirVec(pointListBEND[itr+1],pointListBEND[itr])
                circularPoints = generate_circular_points_v2(center=pointListBEND[itr],
                                                radius=tempRadius,direction_vector=dirVec)
            # Adding Points to VTK array
            for p in circularPoints:
                vtkPoints.InsertNextPoint(p)
```

Now the code is for adding Triangle Strips on the points to add a solid Surface.

```
def AddTriangles(vtkpoints, count):
theta_resolution = count
phi_resolution = 12
torus_cells = vtk.vtkCellArray()
for i in range(theta_resolution+4 ):
    for j in range(phi_resolution):
        torus_cells.InsertNextCell(4)  # Number of points in each triangle strip
        torus_cells.InsertCellPoint(i * phi_resolution + j)
        torus_cells.InsertCellPoint(i * phi_resolution + (j + 1) % phi_resolution)
        torus_cells.InsertCellPoint((i + 1) * phi_resolution + j)
        torus_cells.InsertCellPoint((i + 1) * phi_resolution + (j + 1) % phi_resolution)
return torus_cells
```

[image: Check out this image to See the Results]

It is working perfectly fine but there is an exception case when the Direction Vector (NORMALIZED) is `V = [-0.99861783, 0., 0.05255883]`, which leads to:

```
v1 = [ 0.,0.05255883,-0.]
v2 = [-0.00276243, 0., -0.05248619]
```

this is the point where the Circular Ring rotates a little bit and shifts the points causing a twist, where cylinder is joining.

[image: Check out the result (TWIST)]

What is causing this issue?

One More thing, I am drawing this bend-like Shape using Bezier Curve and then generating circular rings on each point of bezier curve in the Direction of Curve points propagating (`Direction VECTOR (CurvePoint[index + 1]  - CurvePoint[index])`)

Comment: Can you show a little more code? Because there is no `V` in your code, and it uses a mystery variable called `normal`. Please show at least the full function including its `def...` signature.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Please check now. let me know if you need any other details. Thanks